# Converting Jquery hide/show to Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I made a few hide/show panels that I am hoping to use with Vue. The panels are written in Jquery - however when I mount the Jquery functions in Vue, the whole thing seems to fail. The panels do not/hide/show.

Does anyone know why? I have heard that there are issues with Jquery & Vue, but I have not worked out a solution to solve this. Do I need to convert the Jquery to Vue (I'm not even sure how to do this). Can anyone advise on how I could go about fixing this?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/syed263/m4s9Lyed/111/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!--COMPONENT START-->
      <div>
        <div>
          <div id='panel0'>
            <div class="panel_head">
              TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="panel_body">
              BODY
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="btn" id='click' value="Show/Hide"><span id="eee"><i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--COMPONENT END-->


      <!--COMPONENT START-->
      <div>
        <div>
          <div id='panel2'>
            <div class="panel_head">
              TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="panel_body">
              BODY
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="btn" id='click2' value="Show/Hide"><span id="eee"><i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--COMPONENT END-->

      <!--COMPONENT START-->
      <div>
        <div>
          <div id='panel3'>
            <div class="panel_head">
              TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="panel_body">
              BODY
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="btn" id='click3' value="Show/Hide"><span id="eee"><i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i></span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--COMPONENT END-->
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#click').click(function() {
  $("#panel0").toggle("slide");
});

$('#click2').click(function() {
  $("#panel2").toggle("slide");
});

$('#click3').click(function() {
  $("#panel3").toggle("slide");
});


(function() {
  $("#panel0").toggle("slide");
  $("#panel2").toggle("slide");
  $("#panel3").toggle("slide");

}());
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? the fiddle works

Comment: Adding this to a Vue mounted, as a method stops all instances of Vue working. Basically, the page fails to render.

Comment: Can you do that in a forked jsfiddle? It supports vue

Comment: If this is what you expect to happen then it's possible: https://jsfiddle.net/thxopcf4/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually more like two; Do this by using jQuery in Vue, or do this in pure Vue.  Obviously it would be better to convert it to pure Vue, especially if you are only using the `toggle()` method, as importing the whole jQuery library for just one function is major overkill.

---

## With jQuery Version:

To use jQuery in Vue you want to wrap in a Vue component and put v-once directive on the component so Vue leaves it alone.  Then you would usually target the elements using `window.jQuery.('#someid').toggle()`

I distilled the panel component down to be reusable and am targeting it with the following method from within the panel component itself.

```
methods:{
    toggleMe(id){
        window.jQuery('#'+id).toggle('slide');
    }
}
```

Here is the full working fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/cmwtqe7d/3/

---

## No jQuery Version

It is quite easy to replicate jQuery's `toggle()` method since it is only adding/removing "display:none"   You would do this with Vue's class bindings.  No function even necessary in this case. Just create a `hidePanel` data property, write a`.hideme` css class, bind it to div in the template, and toggle it with `hidePanel = !hidePanel` with an @click event.

```
 <div :id='panel.pId' :class="{hideme : hidePanel}">
  <div class="panel_head"> TITLE </div>
  <div class="panel_body"> BODY </div>
</div>
<div>
  <span @click="hidePanel = !hidePanel" class="btn">
    <span id="eee"><i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the working Jfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/L9mq20nd/14/